# Find the extreme values of $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2+4x-4y$ on the region described by $x^2+y^2<=9$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

I've got

$2x+4=2x\lambda$ , $2y-4=2y\lambda$

$\lambda =\frac{x+2}{x}$, $\lambda=\frac{y-2}{y}$

$\frac{x+2}{x}=\frac{y-2}{y}$

$(\frac{x+2}{x})^2+(\frac{y-2}{y})^2$ = 9 //based on another that just used equals the right hand side number like this

and $ x^2+4x+y^2-4y=1$ which didn't get me anywhere.

Also tried

$\frac{y-2}{y}=\frac{x+2}{x}=1+\frac{2}{x}$

$\frac{-2}{y}=\frac{2}{x}$

$(\frac{-2}{y})^2+(\frac{2}{x})^2=9$

The answer are min at (-2, 2) and max at $(\frac{3}{ \sqrt{2}} \frac{-3}{ \sqrt{2}})$

I can kinda of see where you could get the first point from the second thing I tried but no clue about the second point.

Comment: Are you sure those are $\sqrt{3}$ in the denominators for the max, not $\sqrt{2}$?  Geometrically, these should be the points in the radius-$3$ disc centered on the origin that are (min) closest to the point $(-2, 2)$ and (max) furthest from the point $(-2, 2)$.

Comment: Yea, you were right it should be square root of 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because you have found that

$\frac{x+2}{x}=\frac{y-2}{y}$ doesn't mean that 
$x = \frac{x+2}{x}$ and you can plug it into your equation $x^2 + y^2 = 9$

$x = \frac {-2}{1-\lambda}, y = \frac {2}{1-\lambda}$

And plug that into:

$x^2 + y^2 \le 9\\
(-2)^2 + 2^2 \le 9 (1-\lambda)^2\\
0\ge 1-\lambda\le \frac {\sqrt {8}}{3}$

Now before applying calculus, it should be clear:
$f(x) = (x+2)^2 + (y-2)^2 - 8$

$f(x)$ is the square of the distance from the point (-2,2) less a constant.

The absolute minimum is at $(-2,2)$

The maximal distance from the point, inside the disk, is on the boundary of the disk, straight across from the center of the disk.

Answer (score 3):

Hint. Note that
$$f(x,y)=x^2+y^2+4x-4y=(x+2)^2+(y-2)^2-8\geq -8=f(-2,2)$$
Since $(-2,2)$ satisfies $x^2+y^2\leq 9$, it is the global minimum.

Now the maximum should stay on the boundary of the region, that is the circle $x^2+y^2=9$ (why)?, where $f(x,y)=9+4x-4y$.

Comment: Clever avoidance of calculus. +1.

Answer (score 3):

First candidate for extrema, momentarily ignoring the constraint, where both partials are zero
$$
2x+4=0,2y-4=0\Rightarrow (x,y)=(2,-2)
$$
Which is inside the region, as I think you found. As this is a compact space, you must also check the boundary, or where 
$$
x^2+y^2=9
$$
But maximizing this is just a normal lagrangian with constraint that x and y lie on the circle.